# Structures used to store postal codes

Tags: c, struct

It asks me to create a hash function that turns the postal code into an integer by summing its characters. This is my code. I haven't got to the hash function yet.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <string.h>
typedef struct PostalCode
{ 
    int size;
    char *array[6];
} PostalCode;

int main()
{ 
int size = 6, i;
PostalCode *h = malloc(sizeof(PostalCode));
h->size = size; 
h->array = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

printf("Please enter your postal code: \n"); 

for (i=0; i<6; i++) 
    scanf(" %c", &(h->array[i]));
}
```

And the errors I get now are: postalcode.c:9:11: error: assignment to expression with array type 
        h->array = malloc(sizeof(char)*size);

Comment: You are declaring a variable name with the data type `Postalcode`

Comment: `char *array[6];` --> `char array[6];`  `scanf(" %c", &(h->array[i]));`  TTFN

Comment: I still get the exact same error, I get that I needed the %c and the & though

Comment: Those error messages look like you're trying to execute your source file as a shell script.

Comment: BTW, whatever it is that asks you to create a hash function, ask it what it means by summing postal code characters.  For example, if the postal code is 265541, is the sum 2 + 6 + 5 + 5 + 4 + 1 = 23, or is it the sum of the digits' ASCII codes? :)

Comment: it's for canadian postal codes. So the way they work is that it's a letter and then number alternating each time. So for example X3G5T1, so yes i would need to use the ASCII codes of each character and number i enter, and then piece them together as one large number. The way to do that is to shift the current key left by one byte, add the new char or int value to the right most byte, and then XOR the previous leftmost byte everytime a new character or integer is added to the string. But how do i represent that in c?

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
  char *array[6]
```

declares an array of 6 pointers to char, and that's not what you want here.  You can just make it

```
char * array
```

and resolve the error that way, or follow chux's advice, i.e. have

```
char array[6]
```

in which case you don't need the line that's causing the error, just remove it.  No need to dynamically allocate the array.

A few other suggestions:

If your postal code is always 6 characters, then you don't really
need the PostalCode structure, unless you plan on keeping some other
information about the postal code there.  You could just do

```
typedef char PostalCode[6];
```

Of course, if you expect postal codes to have
variable length, then size might help.

Regardless of whether you want a struct or typedef a char array, hard-coding the value 6 is a bad idea.  If it's always 6 characters, then you can `#define` it; or if you keep the size in the structure, then make sure you initialize it and use the struct member instead of the literal number 6.

There is no need to dynamically allocate memory here, but if you do make sure you free it.

Good luck!

Comment: First of all thank you for the char *array; advice. After I fixed that however, the new errors come up: " ./postalcode.c
./postalcode.c: line 2: $'\r': command not found
./postalcode.c: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `(''/postalcode.c: line 3: `void main()"
Also, the only reason I'm using a structure is because my prof asked us to do it this way for practice, otherwise I completely understand that it is unnecessary

Comment: I think now you are getting errors because you are trying to run postalcode.c as a shell script.  You need to compile the source code and then execute the resulting binary.